# How do we create custom marker icon in google map flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-layout

I'm using google map for showing user location.I need a custom marker for showing the user location.user image is getting from the url.but I couldn't able to get the marker like shape as shown in the image.my code is given below.with my code I couldn't able to achieve the required background shape.  anybody please help me on this. [image: this is the requirement]

```
 Future<void> getMarkerIcon(String imagePath, Size size) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

    final Radius radius = Radius.circular(size.width / 2);

    final Paint tagPaint = Paint()..color = Utils.myColor.primary;
    final double tagWidth = 20.0;

    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
    final double shadowWidth = 2.0;

    final Paint borderPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
    final double borderWidth = 2.0;

    final double imageOffset = shadowWidth + borderWidth;

    // Add shadow circle
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, 100),
          topLeft: radius,
          topRight: radius,
          bottomLeft: radius,
          bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        shadowPaint);

    // Add border circle
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
              shadowWidth, shadowWidth, size.width - (shadowWidth * 2), 100),
          topLeft: radius,
          topRight: radius,
          bottomLeft: radius,
          bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        borderPaint);

    // Oval for the image
    Rect oval = Rect.fromLTWH(imageOffset, imageOffset,
        size.width - (imageOffset * 2), size.height - (imageOffset * 2));

    // Add path for oval image
    canvas.clipPath(Path()..addOval(oval));

    // Add image
    ui.Image image = await getImageFromPath(
        imagePath); // Alternatively use your own method to get the image
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, image: image, rect: oval, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);

    // Convert canvas to image
    final ui.Image markerAsImage =
        await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size.width.toInt(), 100);

    // Convert image to bytes
    final ByteData byteData =
        await markerAsImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List uint8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    setState(() {
      markerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(uint8List);
    });
  }

  Future<ui.Image> getImageFromPath(String imagePath) async {
    File imageFile = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imagePath);

    Uint8List imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();

    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();

    ui.decodeImageFromList(imageBytes, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });

    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://pub.dev/packages/custom_map_markers to render any Widget as Marker. Achieving the particular look you want might be easier with a widget

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make widget as marker, instructions are as follow:

[custom map marker](https://medium.com/swlh/using-material-icons-as-custom-google-map-markers-in-flutter-3e854de22e2)

UPDATED

add WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback

Comment: thanks..this works..I'm loading the inner image from the network.if it takes time ,it loads with the placeholder image and marker will be created already.Any solutions for this ?

Comment: Please check my code below and help me to improve..it works fine.but I feel its not the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

```
       class _PostedMapState extends State<PostedMap> {
          Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
          Uint8List imageDataBytes;
          var markerIcon;
          GlobalKey iconKey = GlobalKey();
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
//            if (widget.userImage != '') {
//              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
//                getCustomMarkerIcon(iconKey);
//              });
//            }
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(getCustomMarkerIcon(iconKey));
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build.
            return Container(
              height: widget.height,
              width: widget.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  getMarkerWidget(),
                  Card(
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      onTap: (x) {
                        MapsLauncher.launchCoordinates(
                            widget.checkInLat.toDouble(), widget.checkInLon.toDouble());
                      },
                      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                      zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
                      mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                      trafficEnabled: false,
                      tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                      scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
                      rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
                      myLocationEnabled: false,
                      liteModeEnabled: false,
                      indoorViewEnabled: false,
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng(
                          double.parse(widget.checkInLat),
                          double.parse(widget.checkInLon),
                        ),
                        zoom: 14.4746,
                      ),
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
                        // _mapController = controller;
                        try {
                          _mapController.complete(controller);
                        } catch (err) {
                          Log.e("err", err);
                        }
                      },
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                      markers: Set<Marker>.of(
                        <Marker>[
                          Marker(
                              draggable: false,
                              markerId: MarkerId(widget.userImage),
                              position: LatLng(double.parse(widget.checkInLat),
                                  double.parse(widget.checkInLon)),
                              // icon: currentLocationIcon,
                              icon: markerIcon ?? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        
          Future<void> getCustomMarkerIcon(GlobalKey iconKey) async {
            RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = iconKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
            ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
            ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
            var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
            setState(() {
              markerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(pngBytes);
            });
          }
        
          getMarkerWidget() {
            return Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(50, 50),
              child: RepaintBoundary(
                key: iconKey,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                                '${ASSETS.assetImage("/map_pin_icon2.png")}'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 5,
                        top: 6,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20,
                            child: CommonWidgets().buildCachedNetworkImage(
                              '${widget.userImage}',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: this is the way I implemented it..in the initState I've set a delay for loading the widget and creating the markerIcon..How can we improve this ?

Comment: have you able to make it ? i mean programmatically making the marker type shape... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this online tool. These helped me a lot. [shapemaker.web.app](https://shapemaker.web.app)

Comment: url has %20 in it.

Comment: Don't wait.com 
shapemaker.web.app

Comment: They’re asking for a solution in Flutter, though.

Answer (score 0):

its not 100% of your requirements, maybe helpful
[image]

//to create custom marker for trip planner map
Future createMarkerWithCustomIcon(String imageUrl, LatLng position,
String markerTitle, Function()? onTap) async {
final BitmapDescriptor customIcon =
await getMarkerIcon(imageUrl, Size(150, 150));

final Marker marker = Marker(
markerId: MarkerId(markerTitle),
position: position,
icon: customIcon,
onTap: onTap,
);

return marker;
}

Future getMarkerIcon(String imageUrl, Size size) async {
final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
final Radius radius = Radius.circular(size.width / 2);

final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.white.withAlpha(100);
final double shadowWidth = 15.0;

final Paint borderPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
final double borderWidth = 3.0;

final double imageOffset = shadowWidth + borderWidth;

// Shadow circle
canvas.drawRRect(
RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
topLeft: radius,
topRight: radius,
bottomLeft: radius,
bottomRight: radius,
),
shadowPaint);

// Border circle
canvas.drawRRect(
RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
Rect.fromLTWH(shadowWidth, shadowWidth, size.width - (shadowWidth * 2),
size.height - (shadowWidth * 2)),
topLeft: radius,
topRight: radius,
bottomLeft: radius,
bottomRight: radius,
),
borderPaint);

// Oval for the image
Rect oval = Rect.fromLTWH(imageOffset, imageOffset,
size.width - (imageOffset * 2), size.height - (imageOffset * 2));

// Clip oval path for image
canvas.clipPath(Path()..addOval(oval));

// Fetch and draw the network image
ui.Image image = await _fetchNetworkImage(imageUrl);
paintImage(canvas: canvas, image: image, rect: oval, fit: BoxFit.cover);

// Convert canvas to image
final ui.Image markerAsImage = await pictureRecorder
.endRecording()
.toImage(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());

// Convert image to bytes
final ByteData? byteData =
await markerAsImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
final Uint8List uint8List = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(uint8List);
}

Future<ui.Image> _fetchNetworkImage(String imageUrl) async {
final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
final Uint8List imageBytes = response.bodyBytes;
final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imageBytes);
final ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
return fi.image;
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303133/flutter-custom-marker-and-card-on-google-map